# Cayley-like matrix determinant puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, recreational-mathematics

Let $n_1,\ldots, n_k$ be not necessarily distinct natural numbers.

Let $A$ be a $k\times k$-matrix such that every row and every column of $A$ is a permutation of $n_1,\ldots, n_k$.

What is the range of the determinant of $A$ in terms of $n_1,\ldots, n_k$?

In particular, for which $n_1,\ldots, n_k$ is the determinant constant? For which is it zero?

Comment: The matrices you describe are Latin squares. Determinants of Latin squares have been studied quite extensively. Try a search.

Comment: I thought the definition of a Latin square involved a permutation on the diagonals as well, but I see it doesn't. Thanks!